# URL Rewrite, browser can't find my thumbnails

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I'm using PHP, MYSQL
I've done some research and found out that the relative links are affected by the way the url is written (which I kind of figure it out by then anyway, out of instinct).
My images are held in the root folder of the site like this **images/category/image1.jpg**
**old url: www.mysite.com/mypage.php?this=1&that=2**
**new url: www.mysite.com/keywords/this/that**

How can I make the relative path to take into consideration the old URL or is there a way to redirect all my images requests to my images folder (done maybe in .htaccess also). Or any other solution.

i'm keen on relative paths, no absolute path solutions please

Comment: using `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/files/%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f` to handle routes to existing files?

Comment: My .htaccess is simple so far like this: RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^page_name/([0-9-/|]+)/([0-9-]+)/?$ /Page.php?page=$1&articles=$2 [NC,L].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this link above the `RewriteRule` line so existing files aren't affected by the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

There are others you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # Not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l # Not Symlink
```

More info at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Do I have to add this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f for every Rewrite rule or just once at the top of File?

Comment: You need to add this for every RewriteRule as they are treated individually

Comment: On a separate note; if you're building a website/framework from scratch you may be better off handling the routing with PHP. To do this, you send all requests (not files/directories and other conditions) to index.php by doing `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]`. This way you only need one rule in htaccess and it's much better for security and performance.